# Update nested array with conditions in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I want to create nested array in JavaScript.
I will be getting object like this as input:
`[{size: 12, "text": "aa"}, {size: 11, "text": "ab"}, {size: 10, "text": "ac"}, {size: 12, "text": "ad"}...]`

I want to compare size and create array like structure given below. I wanted to use references to create the same, but JavaScript doesn't have references.
The o/p array will be like this:

```
[{
        "size": 12,
        "text": "a",
        "childrens": [{
                "size": 11,
                "text": "a",
                "childrens": [{
                        "size": 10,
                        "text": "a",
                        "childrens": [{
                            "size": 9,
                            "text": "a",
                            "childrens": []
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "size": 10,
                        "text": "a",
                        "childrens": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "size": 11,
                "text": "a",
                "childrens": [{
                        "size": 10,
                        "text": "a",
                        "childrens": [{
                            "size": 9,
                            "text": "a",
                            "childrens": []
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "size": 10,
                        "text": "a",
                        "childrens": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "size": 12,
        "text": "a",
        "childrens": [{
                "size": 11,
                "text": "a",
                "childrens": [{
                        "size": 10,
                        "text": "a",
                        "childrens": [{
                            "size": 9,
                            "text": "a",
                            "childrens": []
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "size": 10,
                        "text": "a",
                        "childrens": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "size": 11,
                "text": "a",
                "childrens": [{
                        "size": 10,
                        "text": "a",
                        "childrens": [{
                            "size": 9,
                            "text": "a",
                            "childrens": []
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "size": 10,
                        "text": "a",
                        "childrens": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried this:

```
let start = [];
inp.forEach(key => {
   let found = false;
   while(!found) {
      if(start.length === 0 || start[start.length - 1].size === key.size || key.size > start[start.length - 1].size ) {
         start.push({...key, childrens: []})
    found = true;
      }
      else if(start[start.length - 1].size > key.size) {
         start = start[start.length - 1].childrens;
      }
  }
})
```

But in this I know I am reassigning start, which seems to be wrong.
So How can I create an array structure given above?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide more specific and linked between each other input and output? I do not understand what we need to do with the text in the children and why children are array too.

Comment: you will loop through input array, if the size of that element is greater than or equal to the size of last array index element then you will create new element in the array, if the size of element is less than the size of current array index then you will go to child of the last array index. You will repeat this until the location to insert that element is found.

Comment: for eg. in given i/p array above: 1st element is of size 12 and array dont have any element, so you will insert it by default. second element is of size 11, which is less than 12, then you will insert it as child of 12. third is < 12 and also < 11 so you will append it as child of 11. fourth element is of size 12  which is equal to 1st entry of array, so you will create new entry in array. now again if you get size 11, you will insert it as child of 2nd element of array

Comment: you can assume this as indexing. like 1, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.2, 2, 2.1, 2.1.1, 2.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> let inputArr = [{size: 12, "text": "aa"}, {size: 11, "text": "ab"}, {size: 10, "text": "ac"}, {size: 12, "text": "ad"}]
> let outputArr = [];
>
> let findPlace = (output, elem) => {
>   if (output.length === 0) {
>     output.push(elem)
>   }
>   else {
>     let latestOuputElem = output[output.length - 1]
>     if (elem.size >= latestOuputElem.size) {
>       output.push(elem)
>     } else {
>       if (!latestOuputElem.childrens) {
>         latestOuputElem.childrens = []
>       }
>       findPlace(latestOuputElem.childrens, elem)
>     }
>   }
> }
>
> inputArr.forEach(elem => findPlace(outputArr, elem))
>
> // result
> // outputArr = [{"size":12,"text":"aa","childrens":[{"size":11,"text":"ab","childrens":[{"size":10,"text":"ac"}]}]},{"size":12,"text":"ad"}]
> ```